# About elements display in named arrays

Tags: javascript

i have following code
Now i want to display the elements in each place which are comma delimited in a table as for each delimited value in one cell.. means 01 in first cell ABC in second cell, MCA in third cell... how to split plz tell me.. thank you

```
 function showData()
  {
  namedArray['id1']='01,ABC,MCA';
  namedArray['id2']='02,DEF,MCA';
  namedArray['id3']='03,GHI,MCA';
  namedArray['id4']='04,JKL,MCA';
  var i=0;
  var length=0;
  for (var obj in namedArray )
  {
    length++
  }
  alert(length);
  //var x=namedArray['id2'];
    //alert(x);
    var tabid=document.getElementById('mytable');
        var tlength=tabid.rows.length;
        i++;

        var cell1=row.InsertCell(0);
        var cell2=row.InsertCell(0);
        var cell3=row.InsertCell(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var where_is_mytool="home/mytool/mytool.cgi";
var mytool_array=where_is_mytool.split("/");

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
function divide_string()
{
var where_is_mytool="home/mytool/mytool.cgi";
var mytool_array=where_is_mytool.split("/");
alert(mytool_array[0]+" "+mytool_array[1]+" "+mytool_array[2]);
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

You can query the amount of split why using `where_is_mytool.length`